# Rewrite rule php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

can you please give me a rewrite rule for this?

http://www.example.com/?currentpage=2

I need something like: http://www.example.com/curentpage/2.html, or something which is better for seo.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
RewriteRule ^/\?(.*?)=(\d+)$ $1/$2.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I need something to rewrite the urls which contain currentpage, becouse i have other rewrite rules which might conflict...

Comment: What exactly do you mean "you need something to rewrite the urls"? Wouldn't the rewrite rules go into your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

just the same as @limc said but replaced the (.*?) with the currentpage

`RewriteRule ^/\?currentpage=(\d+)$ currentpage/$1.html [R=301,L]`